# Custom datetime picker in JQGRID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid, datetimepicker

Hi bellow is my jqgrid code

```
function fechaReg(el) {
    jQuery(el).datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        timeOnlyTitle: 'Seleccione Horario',
        timeText: 'Hora seleccionada',
        hourText: 'Hora',
        minuteText: 'Minuto',
        secondText: 'Segundo',
        millisecText: 'Milisegundo',
        currentText: 'Ahora',
        closeText: 'Listo',
        ampm: false
    });
}

 jQuery("#correspondence").jqGrid({
        url: '../ajax/selectdata.php',
        editurl: '../ajax/editdata.php',
        mtype: 'post',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['id', 'name', 'total_dept', 'Nombre', 'Fecha y Hora', 'Fecha', 'Hora', 'Consecutivo', 'Tipo de requerimiento', 'Tipo de medio', 'Tipo de Remitente', 'Detalle', 'Observaciones', 'Añadir propiedad', 'Añadir Area'],
        colModel: [
            {name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20, align: "right", hidden: true,editable: false,  editrules: {required: false}},
            {name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 50, editable: true,hidden:true, sorttype: 'text', editrules: {required: true, edithidden: true}},
            {name: 'id_corres_property', index: 'id_corres_property', width: 20, align: "right", hidden: true},
            {name: 'total_dept', index: 'total_dept', width: 20, align: "right", hidden: true},
            {name: 'date_time', index: 'date_time', width: 20, align: "right", hidden: true, editable: true, editoptions: {dataInit: fechaReg, readonly: 'readonly'}, editrules: {required: true, edithidden: true}, search: false},
            {name: 'fecha', index: 'fecha', width: 50, editable: false, editrules: {required: true}, search: false},
            {name: 'hora', index: 'hora', width: 50, editable: false, editrules: {required: true}, search: false},
            {name: 'consecutivo', index: 'consecutivo', width: 55, editable: true, search: false},
            {name: 'type', index: 'type', width: 60, editable: true, sorttype: 'text', editrules: {required: true}, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: {'': '-seleccione-', Normal: 'Normal', Queja: 'Queja', Reclamo: 'Reclamo', Juridico: 'Juridico',Derecho_de_peticion:'Derecho de peticion'}}},
            {name: 'media', index: 'media', width: 50, editable: true, sorttype: 'text', editrules: {required: true}, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: {'': '-seleccione-', Email: 'Email', Personal: 'Personal', Mensajero: 'Mensajero', 'Correo certificado': 'Correo certificado', Fax: 'Fax', 'Pag. web': 'Pag. web'}}},
            {name: 'sender_type', index: 'sender_type', width: '80', editable: true, editrules: {required: true}, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: {'': '-seleccione-', Owner: 'Propietario', Renter: 'Arrendatario', Management: 'Administración', Assignee: 'Codeudor', Garante: 'Apoderado'}},
                stype: "select", searchoptions: {value: "*:Todo;Owner:Propietario;Renter:Inquilino;Management:Administración;Assignee:Codeudor;Garante:Apoderado", defaultValue: "*"}
            },
            {name: 'details', index: 'details', width: 80, editable: true}, 
            {name: 'observations', index: 'observations', width: 80, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', editoptions: {rows: "2", cols: "60"}},
            {name: 'boton_person', index: 'boton_property', sortable: false, width: '50', align: "center", search: false},
            {name: 'boton_office', index: 'boton_office', sortable: false, width: '50', align: "center", search: false}
        ],
        gridComplete: function ()
        {
            var ids = jQuery("#correspondence").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            var allRowsInGrid = jQuery("#correspondence").jqGrid('getRowData');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
            {
                if (allRowsInGrid[i]['id_corres_property'])
                {
                    aP = "<a class='cursorhand' onClick='setProperty(" + ids[i] + ")' style='cursor:pointer;'><img src='../../../admin/public/images/plus_black.png' width='16' height='16' border='0' title='Añadir propiedad' /></a>";
                }
                else
                {
                    aP = "<a class='cursorhand' onClick='setProperty(" + ids[i] + ")' style='cursor:pointer;'><img src='../../../admin/public/images/plus_green.png' width='16' height='16' border='0' title='Añadir propiedad' /></a>";
                }

                jQuery("#correspondence").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {boton_person: aP});

                if (allRowsInGrid[i]['total_dept'] == 0)
                {
                    aO = "<a class='cursorhand' onClick='setArea(" + ids[i] + ")' style='cursor:pointer;'><img src='../../../admin/public/images/plus_green.png' width='16' height='16' border='0' title='Añadir Oficina' /></a>";
                }
                else
                {
                    aO = "<a class='cursorhand' onClick='setArea(" + ids[i] + ")' style='cursor:pointer;'><img src='../../../admin/public/images/plus_black.png' width='16' height='16' border='0' title='Añadir Oficina' /></a>";
                }
                jQuery("#correspondence").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {boton_office: aO});
            }
        },
        width: "1100",
        rowNum: 25,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        pager: '#correspondence-pager',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: " ..:: Correspondencia ::.. ",
        search: true
    });
    jQuery('#correspondence').jqGrid('filterToolbar', {"stringResult": true, "searchOnEnter": false});
    jQuery("#correspondence").jqGrid('navGrid', '#correspondence-pager', {edit: true, add: true, del: false, search: false},
    {recreateForm: true, width: 500}, {recreateForm: true, width: 500}, {recreateForm: true}, {recreateForm: true}).navButtonAdd('#correspondence-pager', {
        caption: "",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-disk",
        onClickButton: function () {

            var filter = {daterange: "fecha"};
            exportFilter("correspondence", 'correspondance', filter);

        },
        position: "last"
    });
```

[image]

My problem is this grid is working fine But I want to customize date time picker

Like if in add mode it should current date and time 
But in edit mode it is inserted date and time .

I tried with this function also

```
function fechaReg(el) {
        jQuery(el).datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            timeOnlyTitle: 'Seleccione Horario',
            timeText: 'Hora seleccionada',
            hourText: 'Hora',
            minuteText: 'Minuto',
            secondText: 'Segundo',
            millisecText: 'Milisegundo',
            currentText: 'Ahora',
            closeText: 'Listo',
            ampm: false
        }).datetimepicker("setDate", new Date());
    }
```

But it is getting current date and time all the time (in add and edit also)
please help me .

if any detail is left then feel free to ask 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
editoptions: 
{ 
   dataInit: function(el) { 
      setTimeout(function() { 
         fechaReg(el); 
      }, 200); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: It was the same behavior as my code..
It only change value after settimeout interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setColProp method to display different date time picker in add and edit mode.

you need to create two function for that and in first function for add mode you can use your existing code to insert current datetime whereas in second function you can pass your custom format that you want.

```
 jQuery('#' + jsonObj.grid.htmlTableId).jqGrid('setColProp', jsonObj.grid.editoptions[j].column_name, {
                       editoptions: {
                            dataInit: function(e){
                             }
                        }
                    });
```

By use of above code you can hook editoptions in loadComplete event of grid.

Comment: editoption works same for add and edit form. I used editoptions in column already.

Comment: have you tried **afterShowForm event handler** of **navGrid**. by using this event handler you can code and register different date picker for add and edit options.

Syntax:

 jQuery(htmlTableId).jqGrid('navGrid', pager,
{
},
{   // edit options
afterShowForm: function(){
},
...
},
{// add options
afterShowForm: function(){
},
...
}
...
);